# Select multiple rows at different intervals

Tags: php, mysql, offset

Is it possible to select one row in MySQL and then miss 4 rows and then miss 3 rows and then miss 5 rows and then loop this until the end of the table?

I have found some LIMIT and OFFSET tutorials online, they work but, are only good for one off set. I need multiple.

I currently have this setup to work in PHP but I feel my PHP code is bloated because I only know a basic way of achieving this.

My PHP code is as follows

```
    $int_count = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guitar_tunings_chords WHERE note_id >= '27'");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

    if ($int_count == 0)$n_1 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 4)$n_2 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 7)$n_3 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 12)$n_4 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 16)$n_5 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 19)$n_6 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 24)$n_7 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 28)$n_8 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 31)$n_9 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 36)$n_10 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 40)$n_11 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 43)$n_12 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 48)$n_13 = ($row["note"]);
    if ($int_count == 52)$n_14 = ($row["note"]);

    $int_count++;   

    }
```

What I am trying to do is select only Major triad notes from the Major scale.

I need to be able to select a base note from a table and then select at 3 different intervals to create chords.

---

Update

```
            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM `guitar_tunings_links`
            JOIN guitar_tunings_chords ON guitar_tunings_links.".$funtion_string." = guitar_tunings_chords.note
            WHERE tuning =  '".$chrd_tn."'") or die(mysql_error());

                while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result2) ) {
                    $bridge_note = ($row["note_id"]);           
                }/*
                var_dump ($key_note);
                var_dump ($bridge_note);
                var_dump ($funtion_string);
                var_dump ($chrd_tn);*/
                    // SELECT * FROM `guitar_tunings_chords` WHERE `note_id` >= 28 LIMIT 0,8
                $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `guitar_tunings_chords` WHERE `note_id` >= ".$bridge_note." LIMIT ".$tuning_capo.",8") or die(mysql_error());
                while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result4) ) {

                    //Notes
                    $note = ($row["note"]); 

                    // Replace # with z
                    $note = str_replace("#", "z", $note);

                    // Distinguish nut notes on or off
                    if (preg_match("/\b".$note."\b/i", $notes_array)) {
                        $n_nut_style = 'note_nut_on';
                    } else { $n_nut_style = 'note_nut_off'; 
                    }

                    // Distinguish fretboard notes on or off
                    if (preg_match("/\b".$note."\b/i", $notes_array)) {
                        $n_style = 'note_on';
                    } else { $n_style = 'note_off'; 
                    }
```

Comment: I know PHP, but I have no clue about guitar chords. I think you should elaborate more on that part.

Comment: You could change offset and send query again

Comment: 1.  You should probably prefer an *array* or some other compound data type rather than scads of index-suffixed variables.  E.g., `array_push($notes, $row["note"])`.  2.  You should ORDER that query explicitly rather than relying on the engine accidentally picking the order you want, even if that happens to be an "implicitly deterministic accident."

Comment: There are 88 notes in my database, around the same for a full size piano. If I play every note with intervals of 4 then 3 then 5 apart I will be hitting a C chord. I want to select all of these notes but mark the ones that land on the intervals as "on" and the rest as "off". Then I can generate chord charts for guitar. like on this page http://www.gtdb.org/tuning_links/chord_generator/chords.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply this to your exact tables but it should work pretty good.

```
select * 
  from (select @i := @i+1 as count, 
               gtc.* from guitar_tunings_chords gtc
         where note_id >= 27) counts 
  join (select @i := -1 as counter) dummy
 where count % 12 = 0 
    or (count-4) % 12 = 0 
    or (count-7) % 12 = 0;
```

% 12 gives one complete cycle of skips, the -4 and -7 (and -0) is the internal offset within each cycle.

Comment: +1 for emulating ROW_NUMBER() and mod'ing your way to the desired rows, as [@Wrikken also suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825605/select-multiple-rows-at-different-intervals/8825828#comment11017620_8825828).

Comment: ROW_NUMBER really should be a native function in MySQL.

Comment: +1 to that.  It's worth mentioning that the `@i` initialization can be put in a derived table:  `... JOIN (SELECT @i := -1 AS "counter") dummy...`.  I bring it up because the very next question is almost always, "Great, but how do I do that in one query?" :)

Comment: I added that. It adds some complexion but I think it's worth it. I normally only write stored procedures so I normally don't think in the lines of "needs to be a onliner cause I use PHP/hibernate/whatever".

Comment: This does look interesting, though I cannot fathom what I am supposed to do with it? I'm not sure what you mean by applying it to my exact table? Does this go in the PHP? I tried to apply it as a query with PHPMyAdmin; it said my query was successful, but there were no results!?

Would I be able to prune off each result into its own variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...I haven't tried it myself but in my head it should work :)

```
$row_count = 0;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guitar_tunings_chords WHERE note_id >= '27'");
$notes = array(); // Notes array
$pattern = array(4,3,5); // Pattern to skip notes
$i = 0; // For pattern position
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($first) { // Add the first note
        $notes[] = $row["note"];
        $first = false;
    } else {
        if($row_count == $pattern[$i]) {
            // Add note
            $notes[] = $row["note"];
            $i++; // Change pattern position
            // Jump to start of pattern
            if($i == 3)
                $i = 0;
            // Reset count
            $row_count = -1;
        }
    }
    $row_count++;
}
```

Comment: I did try this one. But I idealy I need to add each of the selected notes to a variable of which I can then apply a style to indicate if the not is on or off. All notes need to be printed out I just need to indicate which ones are on. The file I am working on is here..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It It looks good though as I can do all of the interval adding from converting Excel cells with commas in between.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, all of the notes are stored in the `$notes` array

Comment: I cant see for my weak PHP knowledge how I could take out the naotes and apply each of them to its own variable like this

global $chrd_tn, $n_1, $n_2, $n_3, $n_4, $n_5, $n_6, $n_7, $n_8, $n_9, $n_10, $n_11, $n_12, $n_13, $n_14, $tuning_capo;

Comment: I don't know what $chrd_tn or $tuning capo means, you can reference each note by doing `$notes[0]` and so on.

Comment: Sorry for including them. They are not relevant to my problem. Maybe I could say IF $notes = true then they = this else this?

Comment: $notes is an array of notes, if you want to assign it to something else you can do: `$n_1 = $notes[0];`

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider possibly using a chord_note table with the intervals (0,4,7,12,16,19, etc) and using that as part of your SELECT, adding the initial note_id value (27) + the entry in the chord_note table

```
SELECT * 
  FROM guitar_tunings_chords 
 WHERE note_id IN ( SELECT 27+chord_interval 
                      FROM chord_note
                  )
```

Getting more fanciful, you could even extend the chord_note table to hold different inteval details for different scales, just modifying the subselect

Comment: It assumes meaningful ID's, but if they are, it will work (I'd throw in an `ORDER BY` though..)

Comment: Although, then without a subselect, it could be: `WHERE id - 27 >= 0 AND ( (( id - 27) % 12 ) = 4 OR ( (id-27) % 12 ) = 7  OR ( id - 27) % 12 = 0) LIMIT 14`

Comment: Thanks for your time Mark. This is certainly something I am now considering. Though I don't actually understand your SQL query I think a new table with only intervals inside would be a great way to achieve this. My code above is for only one chord. I am currently working on this file http://www.gtdb.org/tuning_links/chord_generator/chords.php

Comment: I eventually used your SQL statement Wrikken. Thank you. It took me a while to work it out and fit it to my function but its running just as I want on the page. Hoeever when I try to include the page in a website I am getting a SQL error. One of my variable seems to be empty. but I cannot figure out how to stop it. any idea? It works great on this page http://www.gtdb.org/tuning_links/chord_generator/chords.php?capo=2 but on this page it loses the variable http://www.gtdb.org/tests/

Comment: I have added part of the function that is giving the error to my question at the top. the code where the problem is is this ".$bridge_note." LIMIT ".$tuning_capo.",8"